# how to create a frequency matrix from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

say I have df:

```
df <- data.frame(cell = c("c1", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"),
                 layer = c("L1", "L2", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L4", "L4", "L3"))
> df
  cell layer
1   c1    L1
2   c1    L2
3   c2    L1
4   c3    L2
5   c4    L3
6   c5    L3
7   c6    L4
8   c7    L4
9   c8    L3
```

how would I create a frequency matrix like:

```
> table(df$cell, df$layer)
    
     L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  1  0  0
  c2  1  0  0  0
  c3  0  1  0  0
  c4  0  0  1  0
  c5  0  0  1  0
  c6  0  0  0  1
  c7  0  0  0  1
  c8  0  0  1  0
```

but in a for loop? i tried something like:

```
> for(layer in unique(df$layer)){
+   df[paste(layer)] <- ifelse(df$layer == layer, 1, 0)
+ }
> df
  cell layer L1 L2 L3 L4
1   c1    L1  1  0  0  0
2   c1    L2  0  1  0  0
3   c2    L1  1  0  0  0
4   c3    L2  0  1  0  0
5   c4    L3  0  0  1  0
6   c5    L3  0  0  1  0
7   c6    L4  0  0  0  1
8   c7    L4  0  0  0  1
9   c8    L3  0  0  1  0
```

but it one-hots the rows and adds it back to the original dataframe...
I was looking at the source-code of `base:::table` but couldn't pick out the part i'm curious about. Is there a way to "push" into an empty matrix?
something like:

```
newMat <- Matrix(0, nrow = length(unique(df$cell)), ncol=length(unique(df$layer)))
for (i in 1:length(unique(df$cell))){
  for (j in 1:length(unique(df$layer)))){
    newMat[i,j] <- ....
  }
}
```

Just not sure how to complete it... thanks!
expected output, in matrix form:

```
     L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  1  0  0
  c2  1  0  0  0
  c3  0  1  0  0
  c4  0  0  1  0
  c5  0  0  1  0
  c6  0  0  0  1
  c7  0  0  0  1
  c8  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Could you also add expected output?

Comment: @Cole, just added it, sorry about that. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. And instead of `table(df$cell, df$layer)` you want that done in a loop? Sorry, I know you said that, but most questions are more the other way around - how to I vectorize a loop.

Comment: @Cole I'm using some reference python code, which is slightly the same: ` # Create adjacency matrix
def compute_adjacency(pairs, idx):
    
    adj = np.zeros((n, n))
    
    for pair in pairs:
        l, r = tuple(pair)
        i = idx[l]
        j = idx[r]
        adj[i,j] = 1
        adj[j,i] = 1
        
    return adj` i'm not sure how to do this in R however. and given my slightly different dataset, the closest i thought of would be a for loop but for my situation

Comment: sorry, i'm not super familiar with stackoverflow either, so the formatting of that last comment is horrendous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to use a loop:

```
df <- data.frame(cell = c("c1", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"),
                 layer = c("L1", "L2", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L4", "L4", "L3"))


cells = unique(df$cell)
layers = unique(df$layer)

res = matrix(0L, 
             nrow = length(cells),
             ncol = length(layers),
             dimnames = list(cells, layers))

for (i in seq_along(cells)) {
  cols = match(df[df$cell == cells[i], 'layer'], layers)
  res[i, cols] = 1L
}

res

##    L1 L2 L3 L4
## c1  1  1  0  0
## c2  1  0  0  0
## c3  0  1  0  0
## c4  0  0  1  0
## c5  0  0  1  0
## c6  0  0  0  1
## c7  0  0  0  1
## c8  0  0  1  0
```

The two biggest things is that since we need to use the unique `cell` and `layers` multiple times, it can be more performant to assign to a variable instead of using `unique` more than once. Then, this `match(df[df$cell == cells[i], ...])` call is to determine which layers are there so we can assign `1` to them.

Note, I would not do this at all. I recommend using `table` or some sort of reshaping mechanism.

Comment: using ```table``` is because it's more efficient?

Comment: It should be more efficient. Note, `df$cell == cells[i]` is largely a group by activity. That is, if we were to group directly, we would only pass through the `df$cell` vector more-or-less once. With the filter approach, we are instead passing through `df$cell` the number of unique elements of `cell`. I mainly attempted to make it more of a loop per a post.

Comment: ah okok, i understand. thank you! i'll just stick with table() then, but thanks for showing the for loop and ```match``` function, i didn't know it